# NFC implemetation in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, nfc

I am planning to implement NFC in iPhone. I would like to know that iOS7 can use NFC sdk.
When I research about NFC, I found that is the new sdk for iOS 11 and heigher. I just found out some examples for NFC but they are implemented using swift. I also would like to know that I can also use objective c to implement NFC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CoreNFC from Objective-C on iOS 11.

Be aware that it is only supported iPhone 7 and 7plus (presumably it will also be supported on any new phones that are released).

You cannot use it in iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11 contains Core NFC framework and it works only for tag reading. Reading NFC NDEF tags is supported on iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus. Of course, you can use Objective-C for your application. And you can't use NFC on iOS 7. Read more in [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc). And [here](https://github.com/artemnovichkov/iOS-11-by-Examples#core-nfc) is my basic example of using Core NFC.